# Entity Error: The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm having an error when using the entitiy framework that says the following:
"The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once"

Solutions from similar questions on stackoverflow, mentioned adding ".ToList()" to my query but that didn't help either.  Here's my code:

```
List<Kit> kits = new List<Kit>();

            var storedProc = db.GetOrderDetails(orderNumber).ToList();

            foreach (var proc in storedProc.ToList())
            {
                 [...content here]
            }
```

My code successfully queries the first time through. No issues.  When I re-click my submit button with a new "orderNumber", it throws this error.

I've also tried other solutions such as .AsEnumerable().ToList(), but still no luck.  Any idea why this may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the ToList() in only one place? In the code above you're calling ToList() on a List. Don't know if that's your problem, but that'd be the first thing i try.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too but no luck.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `GetOrderDetails`? Maybe that method is illegally storing and re-using a `Queryable`

Comment: Is the exception thrown on `GetOrderedDetails` line or `storedProc.ToList()` line?

Answer (score 0):

Having said that you have tried "`.ToList()`" in one place, and `AsEnumerable().ToList()`

Glad if this could help!
Step 1:

```
var veryFirst = storedProc.First();
```

Step 2:

```
var returnValues = veryFirst.ReturnCode;
```

and try taking this then on to see if it works? Else you may try using `IQueryable`